# Authenticity Of A Narration That Says That Prophet (Sallallahu'alaihiwassalam) Used To Visit His Wives Equally?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

I know there are many Sahih narrations that say that Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alaihiwassalam) used to visit his wives equally. However, my question in here is about this particular Hadith with **these particular wordings**.

My question is about the following narration:-

> Allah's Prophet (Sallallahu'alaihiwassalam) used to divide visits to
> his wives equally and say, "O Allah, this is my division concerning
> what I possess, so do not blame me concerning what You possess and I
> do not."

This narration is found in the following Hadith collections:-

Bulugh Al-Maram, Book 8, Hadith 104

Mishkat Al-Masabih, 3235

Sunan Abu Dawud, 2134

Jami' At-Tirmidhi, 1140

According to some sources, Hakim and Ibn Hibban graded the version in Bulugh Al-Maram as authentic. However, Imam Tirmidhi has stated that it is Mursal narration due to a missing link in the transmitters of the narration. As far as the version in Mishkat Al-Masabih is concerned, Albani has declared it as *Jayid*. However, I am not sure if Albani is correct in his gradings because Albani has been criticized a lot by Hadith scholars for his gradings. As far as the version in Jami' At-Tirmidhi is concerned, it has been narrated by the following chain of transmitters:-

Muhammad bin Yahya bin Abi Umar (Found In Sahih Muslim 2003h, 1341c, etc)

Bashr bin al-Sari al-Afwah (Found in Sahih Al-Bukhari 7048 and Sahih Muslim 1452e, 635b, 2351b)

Hammad bin Salama (Found in Sahih Muslim 2567b, 2379, etc)

The link between Ayoub al-Sakhtiyani and Abu Qilabah can be found in Sahih Al-Bukhari 5517, 5463, Sahih Muslim 110c, and in various places in the Sahihyaen)

Abdullah bin Yazid bin Zayd (Found In Sahih Bukhari 5516, 4414, 1159, etc)

Aisha bint Abi Bakr (May Allah Be Pleased With Her) is obviously a reliable narrator.

So is this narration with these particular wording suitable to quote and is it Sahih (authentic)?

Comment: What do you mean by "Used to visit his wives equally" ? In what sense?

Comment: @Ghz... - Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alaihiwassalam) was fair to all of his wife and he used to treat them equally and fairly. This is what I meant.

Comment: Still waiting for a knowledgeable brother/sister to answer this question.